# An error when trying to start a service

Tags: windows, service, windows-services

In services.msc, when I right-click on my service and choose "start", I get the following error: [image]

This is a service that I created in VS2008 (using c#).
Is it a error in the code? Did the installation itself went wrong?

Comment: Look in the windows event viewer for more information. Then post the error. Otherwise you question has no information for anyone to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with Richard... diagnostics are the best way to gather information.

That being said, I typically put a line of code in the OnStart event that will force a break.  That way, you can step through it in the debugger and see if there is an issue within OnStart or if it completes successfully but there is no other work to be done.  It's not the most graceful way to do it, but it works.

In OnStart, add the following:

```
System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Launch();
```

See this blog post for a walkthrough:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/field_notes/archive/2008/07/21/how-to-debug-windows-service-onstart.aspx

Obviously, you want to remove that for production code.

Comment: Thanks!! Exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

You will have to debug the service.

The message box is telling you that the process exited normally, it wasn't an unhanded exception. There may be more details in the event log, but if your service didn't provide any diagnostics<sup>1</sup> then there is nothing for Windows to tell you.

---

<sup>1</sup> Imagine this occurs on a machine to which you don't have access, how would you work out what is happening? Services need diagnostics, and ideally configurable diagnostics to allow subsequent tracing of what happened.